# Re-order nested json with jq

Tags: json, key, jq

I have this simple JSON which has a name and a nested info with telephone and address, but now I want my address to show first before telephone.  How do I do this with jq?

Sample:

```
 jq . sample.json
{
  "name": "john",
  "info": {
    "telephone": "444-5555",
    "address": "1234 Main st"
  }
}
{
  "name": "jane",
  "info": {
    "telephone": "222-3333",
    "address": "1234 Eagle st"
  }
}
```

Ultimately, I want address before telephone:

```
{
  "name": "john",
  "info": {
    "address": "1234 Main st"
    "telephone": "444-5555",
  }
}
```

So I would do something like this:

```
 jq ". | {name: .name, info: [.info.address, .info.telephone]}" sample.json
```

But this would give me instead:

```
{
  "name": "john",
  "info": [
    "1234 Main st",
    "444-5555"
  ]
}
{
  "name": "jane",
  "info": [
    "1234 Eagle st",
    "222-3333"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Oops, it was easy as:

```
jq ". | {name: .name, info: {address: .info.address, telephone: .info.telephone}}" sample.json
```

Result:

```
{
  "name": "john",
  "info": {
    "address": "1234 Main st",
    "telephone": "444-5555"
  }
}
{
  "name": "jane",
  "info": {
    "address": "1234 Eagle st",
    "telephone": "222-3333"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just: `.info |= {address,telephone}`